# How do I use a lambda expression in C# to process a matrix LinkedList<Object>?

Tags: c#, linq, matrix, lambda

I'm new to lambda expressions (C#) and would like some help with a problem:

I have a matrix that is a LinkedList of objects. Each object contains 3 positive integers. V1, V2 and V3.

1) Calculate the absolute value of V1-V2, V2-V3 and V1-V3 for each line (LinkedList) in the matrix.

2) Find the highest of each ABS calculation for each line.

3) Return the average of the highest of all of the lines.

I can tackle this problem with logical statements and temporary lists. In my quest of being adept with lambda's, I'm hoping that a lambda expression could solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

prenone request:

```
LinkedList<Stock> stockLL = new LinkedList<Stock>();

class Stock
{

    protected int _date;
    protected double _open;
    protected double _close;
    protected double _high;
    protected double _low;
    protected int _volume;


    public int date { get => _date; private set => _date = value; }
    public double open { get => _open; private set => _open = value; }
    public double close { get => _close; private set => _close = value; }
    public double high { get => _high; private set => _high = value; }
    public double low { get => _low; private set => _low = value; }
    public int volume { get => _volume; private set => _volume = value; }


    public Stock(int date, double open, double close, double high, double low, int volume)
    {
        _date = date;
        _open = open;
        _close = close;
        _high = high;
        _low = low;
        _volume = volume;

    }
}
```

Not sure that it matters but if you are curious. V1 = "high", V2 = "Low" and V3 = is the previous day's opening. The calculation is to calculate the Average True Range of an instrument. I simplified my question to balance me possibly confusing the reader with my ability to figure out the rest on my own.

```
    public double High(LinkedList<Stock> stockLL) //High and Low here are unrelated to the high and low in the ATR calc. I'm just showing them as an example of my first lambdas.
    {
        return stockLL.Max(t => t.high);
    }

    public double Low(LinkedList<Stock> stockLL)
    {
        return stockLL.Min(t => t.low);
    }

    public double ATR(LinkedList<Stock> stockLL)
    {

        Insert Genius Lambda Here!

        return 
    }
```

Comment: Could you add some code to your question, like the declaration of the LinkedList?

Comment: Added @prenone. Hopefully, I'm doing this correctly. This is really my first post :-) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```cs
public double ATR(LinkedList<Stock> stockLL)
{
    return stockLL.Select(stock => new[]
            {
                Math.Abs(stock.high - stock.low),
                Math.Abs(stock.low - stock.open),
                Math.Abs(stock.open - stock.high)
            }.Max())
        .Average();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I had no idea that you could nest a lambda this way. Cheers, Kyle.